# Selenium hangs while getting New random session seed

Tags: selenium

I faced this issue on Digital Ocean Droplet (apparently it is related to VMs, but AWS worked fine for me.)

The problem is that selenium-server randomly started hanging. Most of the times it will not just start (sometimes, rarely it will though) and terminate with the error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to selenium
at hasStarted ....
```

On using -debug, I could find out that it hung on

```
12:18:53.686 DEBUG - New random session seed
```

After hours of troubleshooting, I cam across this post. Posting here for anyone who may face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1301

Use: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -debug -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
```